# Terminator screen default position

Tags: layout, configuration, terminator

I want to force Terminator to open at the top-left of my screen. When I saved the layout I had the window positioned correctly. However, whenever I open Terminator upon computer restart, the window is positioned near the top and about 1.5 inches from the left.

I've been messing around with the config file, but cannot figure out the 'position' paramters. For example, under `[[[child0]]]` :

```
position = 36:32
```

and under `[[[child1]]]` :

```
position = 834
```

Can anyone explain how to customize these parameters?

System info:

- Ubuntu 17.10, kernel 4.13.0-43
- screen dimensions: 1920x1080 pixels, or 508x286 mm
- Terminator v 1.91

terminator/config :

```
[global_config]
  always_split_with_profile = True
  suppress_multiple_term_dialog = True
  title_transmit_bg_color = "#8ae234"
[keybindings]
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_term = a69b1a79-eb9d-4c15-ac27-0502efc4c4f7
      last_active_window = True
      maximised = False
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      position = 36:32
      size = 808, 1014
      title = bp@bpenner: ~
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      position = 834
      ratio = 0.826560951437
      type = VPaned
    [[[terminal2]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child1
      profile = BP
      type = Terminal
      uuid = a69b1a79-eb9d-4c15-ac27-0502efc4c4f7
    [[[terminal3]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      profile = BP
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 454d7873-3e55-49a4-af8c-6456f99d5e1e
[plugins]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
```

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: @accasio unfortunately not

Answer (score 20):

There are a couple of things to try.

The following worked for me:

1. Open Terminator, then adjust its window's size and position as desired.
2. In the Terminator window, in the command-line area, right-click then choose **Preferences**.
3. In the **Layouts** tab, expand the **Type** / **Name** list, select **Terminal1**, then click **Save**.
4. Exit the *Preferences* dialog, then close and re-open Terminator.

Another approach that one can use to configure the display properties of many  applications is to add the `--geometry=` parameter to the application's command line.

1. In a shell command line, type `man x` to display the man page for the X window system.
2. Scroll down to **GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS**.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that your config file is missing the first [[[window0]]] entry, which comes before the [[[child]]] entries on my default settings.

Here are my config settings in which the first window starts with the upper left corner at position y=100 and x=100 pixels and it's size is 1000 X 700 pixels.
(notice the different format required to make these entries)

```
[global_config]

[keybindings]
[profiles]
[[default]]
audible_bell = True
cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
[layouts]
[[default]]
[[[window0]]]
  type = Window
  parent = ""
  size = 1000 , 700
  position = 100:100
[[[child1]]]
  type = Terminal
  parent = window0


[plugins]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to set terminator windows on the top left corner on 4k display (ubuntu 22.04):

- Edit config file `nano ~/.config/terminator/config`
- Under `[[[window0]]]` add `size` and `position`:

```
    [[[window0]]]
      type = Window
      size = 1920, 1080
      position = 0:0
      parent = ""
```